# How do I programmatically check whether a custom entity is stored in external database?

Tags: database

In Drupal 8, how do I programmatically check whether a custom entity is stored in the external database using the entity ID?

Do we have any method/service to check whether a custom entity is stored in an external database using the entity ID?

Comment: Cross-posted on https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2995238

Answer (score 0):

Presuming you have configured the external database correctly inside `settings.php` you have to use `db_set_active('MYEXTERNALDATABASE')`, then do your DB query to check for your ID and when you're done `db_set_active('default')` set the active database back.

[`db_set_active`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21includes%21database.inc/function/db_set_active/8.2.x)

> Sets a new active database.

Comment: Hi @leymannx: Thanks. please guide me how to do that in system.install file as per this thread - https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2995238 because it is core file.

Comment: @vignesh.rajendran11 - Which is a totally different question. Please ask a new question.

Comment: Hi @leymannx: it's okay but your answer is not relevant for our question because we are expecting the method/service to get database details of custom entity. Anyways thanks for help.